# How is a return value of AnyObject! different from AnyObject

Tags: swift, forced-unwrapping

The `NSMetadataItem` class in the Cocoa framework under Swift contains the following function:

`func valueForAttribute(key: String!) -> AnyObject!`

I'm still learning the difference (and details) between forced unwrapping and optional chaining. In the above function, does this mean:

1. The `key` parameter must have a value, and
2. The return value is guaranteed to have a value?

My primary concern is with *the exclamation point following* the return value - once I have assigned the return value:

```
var isDownloadedVal = item.valueForAttribute(NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey)
```

Do I need to include an `if let` block when examining it, or am I guaranteed that it will have a value I can examine safely?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

TLDR: Treat `Foo!` as if it were `Foo`.

Many Cocoa calls include implicitly unwrapped optionals, and their need for it is very likely the reason the feature even exists. Here's how I recommend thinking about it.

First, let's think about a simpler case that doesn't involve `AnyObject`. I think `UIDevice` makes a good example.

```
class func currentDevice() -> UIDevice!
```

What's going on here? Well, there is always a `currentDevice`. If this returned `nil` that would indicate some kind of deep error in the system. So if we were building this interface in Swift, this would likely just return `UIDevice` and be done with it. But we need to bridge to Objective-C, which returns `UIDevice*`. Now that should never be `nil`, but it syntactically *could* be `nil`. Now in ObjC, we typically ignore that fact and don't `nil`-check here (particularly because `nil`-messaging is typically safe).

So how would we express this situation in Swift? Well, technically it's an `Optional<UIDevice>`, and you'd wind up with:

```
class func currentDevice() -> UIDevice?
```

And you'd need to explicitly unwrap that every time you used it (ideally with an `if let` block). That would very quickly drive you insane, and for nothing. `currentDevice()` always returns a value. The `Optional` is an artifact of bridging to ObjC.

So they invented a hack to work around that (and I think it really is a hack; I can't imagine building this feature if ObjC weren't in the mix). That hack says, yes, it's an `Optional`, but you can pretend it's not, and we promise it's always going to be a value.

And that's `!`. For this kind of stuff, you basically ignore the `!` and pretend that it's handing you back a `UIDevice` and roll along. If they lied to you and return `nil`, well, that's going to crash. They shouldn't have lied to you.

This suggests a rule: don't use `!` unless you really need to (and you pretty much only need to when bridging to ObjC).

In your specific example, this works in both directions:

```
func valueForAttribute(key: String!) -> AnyObject!
```

Technically it takes an `Optional<String>`, but only because it's bridged to `NSString*`. You *must* pass non-`nil` here. And it technically returns you `Optional<AnyObject>`, but only because it's bridged to `id`. It promises that it won't be `nil`.

Comment: Great explanation. Thinking about the bridging to ObjC makes the whole Optional concept make a lot more sense.

Comment: Thank you, that's an excellent explanation. "If they lied to you and return nil, well, that's going to crash. They shouldn't have lied to you." <- That answers my sub-question of what would happen if they *tried* to return a nil value.

Comment: 【   class func JSONObjectWithData(data: NSData!, options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions, error: NSErrorPointer) -> AnyObject!   】 I'm a little confused with this NSJSONSerialization class func. When doing with invalid json, it will still returning a nil, so why not use ? but !

Comment: The ObjC->Swift API conversion was almost certainly done by automated tools (or by automated humans, also called "interns"). I strongly doubt they carefully considered the semantics of each method call. In this case, `AnyObject?` would make more sense, and you should open a radar (bugreport.apple.com) to request that. Probably any method that takes an NSErrorPointer should return ?.

Comment: I've been puzzled by this too, so thanks for the great explanation. I was especially confused as to why the table view argument in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is typed as "UITableView?" -- I noticed that if you use code completion, you get, "UITableView!", but if you look at the boilerplate code you get with a UITableViewController it gives you UITableView?. Since the table view calls this data source method, the tableView argument can never be nil, so it wasn't clear (before your answer) why you would need any sort of optional.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Swift-eBook, which states the following

*„Trying to use ! to access a non-existent optional value triggers a runtime error. Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil value before using ! to force-unwrap its value.“*

I would answer to your first two questions with **Yes**.

> Do I need to include an if let block when examining it...

**No**, this is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks - I think I understand the use of `?` and `!` when defining/accessing variables, but am a little unsure of their use in method signatures. Does this mean that a runtime error would occur if the `valueForAttribute` function tried to return a nil value?

Comment: It means that valueForAttribute can't even return nil, because the type it hast to return ends with !. And so nil can never be assigned to the value the function returns.
And I don't think Apple's libraries are build to trigger runtime-errors.