# Why do some UIKit functions return implicity unwrapped optionals?

Tags: uikit, swift

I'm looking at some of the UIKit headers in Swift, in particular the one for `UIViewController` and there's a couple of functions that return implicity unwrapped optionals rather than plain optionals.

For example:

`// The rotating header and footer views will slide out during the rotation and back in once it has completed.
    func rotatingHeaderView() -> UIView! // Must be in the view hierarchy. Default returns nil.
    func rotatingFooterView() -> UIView! // Must be in the view hierarchy. Default returns nil.`

Default value they're returning is nil. Surely returning plain optionals would be better in this case to let the developer know that what's being returned is very likely to be a nil value?

Comment: The implicitly unwrapped optional is very much like the standard variable in ObjC - It can be nil and you can access properties directly. It more seemlessly carries the experience over from ObjC to Swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicitly unwrapped optionals are the best match for the objects we used (past tense, amirite?) in Objective-C. They let you both use the returned value directly (without needing optional operators `?` or `!`) but still query them for `nil` value.

For more see [Rob Napier's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24061401/59541) to a related question.

Comment: OK, so it's more a case of bridging ObjC to Swift than it is good practice?

Comment: I believe so. This answer has a much better, more in-depth explanation: [How is a return value of AnyObject! different from AnyObject](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24061401/59541)

Comment: @Harry Yup. You can get more of a flavour of this from the Swift Interoperability In Depth WWDC video; definitely worth a watch at this point if you're getting curious about this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Without reading into the minds of the language authors, it's hard to say for certain why some UIKit functions return implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Presumably, these functions *do* contain a value (are non-`nil`). So one reason why the optional is used, explicitly unwrapped, could be to make it possible to allow type checking through optional binding:

```
if let definiteString = assumedString {
    println(definiteString)
}
```

Comment: With an implicitly unwrapped optional you can just say `if assumedString { println(assumedString) }`.

Comment: If you wanted to treat it like a normal optional, sure. This is optional binding.