# Forced unwrap of a return type?

Tags: swift, forced-unwrapping

I'm starting to get my head around optionals and forced unwrapping, except for in one particular context: when it is a return type to a function.

What is the difference between:

```
func myFunction() -> NSData { ... }

func myFunction() -> NSData! { ... }

func myFunction() -> NSData? { ... }
```

Furthermore, when I use a return value of `NSData!`, I am forced to use `?` which seems odd.

```
func myFunction() -> NSData! { ... }
let data = myFunction()
data?.write()
```

Why do I need the `?` if I force unwrapped the return?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061039/how-is-a-return-value-of-anyobject-different-from-anyobject

Comment: For `NSData`, there is nothing different between those two lines of code. You can find a good explanation from Rob in the link sent by @rmaddy.

Comment: In practice **never** use implicit unwrapped optional values as return types in functions / methods. Either the value can be `nil` then use `?` or the value will never be `nil` then use a `non-optional`.

Comment: The answer linked by @rmaddy doesn't explain why Swift uses type `NSData?` for the `data` variable in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> func myFunction() -> NSData { ... }
> ```

The above means that `myFunction` returns an instance of `NSData`.

---

> ```
> func myFunction() -> NSData? { ... }
> ```

The above means that `myFunction` returns a value of type `Optional<NSData>` (also called `NSData?`). `Optional` is an `enum` with two cases: `.some(value)` and `.none` (also called `nil`). So the function returns either an `NSData` (wrapped in the `.some` case), or `nil`.

---

> ```
> func myFunction() -> NSData! { ... }
> ```

The above means that `myFunction` returns a value of type `Optional<NSData>`, **just like** the `NSData?` return type in the previous example.

However, the use of `!` means that, if you use the value of `myFunction()` in a way that doesn't type-check, the compiler will try unwrapping the returned value for you. So if you say this:

```
let maybeLength = myFunction()?.length
```

then the compiler will see that you are treating the return value of `myFunction` as an `Optional<NSData>`. But if you say this:

```
let dataLength = myFunction().length
```

then the compiler will see that `Optional<NSData>` doesn't have a `length` member, so it will pretend you wrote this:

```
let dataLength = myFunction()!.length
```

and if that compiles, it will carry on.

This behavior was defined in [Swift Evolution proposal SE-0054, Abolish `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9cf2685293108ea3efcbebb7ee6a8618b83d4a90/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md).

---

Now let's finally consider this:

> ```
> func myFunction() -> NSData! { ... }
> let data = myFunction()
> data?.write()
> ```

What is the type of `data`? The compiler has to infer the type of `data` based on the expression on the right side of the `=`. As I explained in the example above, the type of `myFunction()` is `Optional<NSData>`. So the type of `data` is `Optional<NSData>`, also called `NSData?`.

The compiler doesn't run into any trouble making `data`'s type `NSData?`, so it has no reason to implicitly unwrap the return value of `myFunction`.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!

Comment: Could I conclude that a forced unwrapped return value is dangerous because it may cause an app crash when `nil` is returned?

Comment: It’s dangerous to force-unwrap an Optional that might be nil. If you know the function won’t return nil (based on what you’re passing it), it’s safe to force unwrap the value it returns.